# HTML - OnChange update image source url from input box

Tags: html, image, input

Okay, I am working on my final for a webpage design class. We can ONLY use HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT. No AJAX or anything else.

I need a little help.

I have a text box. I want the user to be able to paste an (image) url into it, and it will automatically update an image on the page to the image url they pasted.

Is this possible?

Can I use OnChange in the textbox to update my image url? What do I put in each?

Here is my textbox

```
<input id="usrimg" onChange="??(What do I put here)??" type="text"/>
```

and here is the image source I want to change OnChange in the text input

```
        imageObj.src = "??What goes here??";
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a late answer but,
have you tried something like this?
I know it is not the best solution, but it is something...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt() {
var image_url = prompt("Please enter an image url","http://hasselt-graphix.be/images/HGX.png");
  document.write("<!-- The rest of your html page --><img src=\"" + image_url +   "\" width=\"400px\"><!-- The rest of your html page-->"); 
}
</script>

<form>
  <input type="button" value="Change picture" onclick="show_prompt();" />
</form>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeUrl(el) {
    var el = document.getElementById('inputid').value;
    var im = document.getElementsByTagName(img);
    im.src = el;
    }
    </script>


<input type="text" id="inputid" value="" onBlur="changeUrl(this.value)"/>
```